# Detecting a Windows Update Automatic Restart with VB.NET (Before it happens)

Tags: vb.net, windows-update

My office computer automatically restarts (group policy). I would like to have an app that simply detects that an automatic restart is going to happen, and perform an action (send an email to me). A possible path I found was [ARR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948909(v=vs.85).aspx)

(which I found by this question: [Detect whether a Windows reboot was due to Windows updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647741/detect-whether-a-windows-reboot-was-due-to-windows-updates))

However, this is in C, C++, and I'm really just a noob with rudimentary VB.net knowledge. A possible path would be to use [GetProcessByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) if the automatic update restart is performed by a specific process. Thus my questions are:

- Is there a specific process that's started for a Windows Automatic Restart?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ARR is probably the most correct way to do this.

To try and stick more to your wheelhouse, you could write a VB app that runs on startup and searches the event logs similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140092/how-can-i-get-the-windows-last-reboot-reason)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! So the problem with doing anything after the restart, is that it requires me to log-in, which is not automatic (I want the email sent so that I know I have to go to the computer, and log-in and restart all the time-sensitive stuff I had churning away... darn forced restarts!)

Comment: Actually depending on what version of windows, or your comfort level with writing services, it wouldn't necessarily require a logon.  Windows 7 scheduled tasks can be triggered at startup, or a service could both get you what you need.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks! I'll have to check into those options.